# iOS -GeoFire ExceptionThrown 'Precision must be less than 23!' when Search Radius is to Wide

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mkmapview, geofire

I have a mapView and the users can choose a zoom radius of 1 mi, 10 mi, 20 mi, and 30 mi to search for restaurants from wherever their device is. I have all the restaurant's lat-lon saved inside a GeoFire path.

When the user decides to search, first I get the user/s location, then I let the user choose a mile radius, then I get the mapView to zoom to that radius:

```
var selectedRadius = 0.0
let milesToMeters = 1609.344
let doubleDistance = 2  // according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025970/4833705 to get a mapView radius of x miles, the distance needs to be doubled
var circleQuery: GFCircleQuery?
var queryHandle: UInt?

// 1. get the user's current location
guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else { return }
let lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
let lon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
let center = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

// 2. user picks 10 mile radius
selectedRadius = (10 * doubleDistance) * milesToMeters

// 3. get the region I want to use for zoom in the mapView
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center.coordinate, selectedRadius, selectedRadius)
mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
```

I then want to get all the restaurants in that 10 mile radius from GeoFire and I run:

```
// 4. geoFire ref
let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("restaurant_locations")
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

// 5. since I had doubled the selectedRadius for the MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance I now cut it in half to get the regular 10 mile radius in meters
let initialRadius = (selectedRadius / doubleDistance)

// 6. this is the radius I want to run the geoFire query on
circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: center, withRadius: initialRadius)

// 7. observe .keyEntered at that query
queryHandle = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in ...
```

On step 7, when trying to observe the `.keyEntered` I get the exception:

> 'Precision must be less than 23!

I then tried to set a span using GeoFire's Region query `query(with:)` but I got the same exact exception thrown

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(initialRadius, initialRadius)
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center.coordinate, span)
geoFire.query(with: region).observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in ...
```

**When choosing a MapView zoom radius of 10 mi, 20, or 30 mi, how can I run a GeoFire query to match that radius?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old answer I gave with the nautical miles showed the incorrect distance on the map.

The correct way is to [double the number of miles you want to span then multiple that by 1609.344](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025970/4833705) (1 mile is 1609.344 meters) and set that result as the `CLLocationDistance`s along with your location inside `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance()` (step 3 below)

Use `GFRegionQuery` (step 6 below) instead of a `GFCircleQuery` to use the `geoFire` region

Basically just do the conversion in step 2 below, use the region from step 3 below, and set it as the region to use in step 6 below.

```
var radiusConversion = 0.0
let milesToMeters = 1609.344
let doubleDistance = 2
var regionQuery: GFRegionQuery?
var queryHandle: UInt?

// 1. get the user's current location
guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else { return }
let lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
let lon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
let center = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

// 2. user picks 10 mile radius and do the conversion based on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025970/4833705
radiusConversion = (10 * doubleDistance) * milesToMeters

// 3. set the region I want to use for zoom in the mapView
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center.coordinate, radiusConversion, radiusConversion)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true) // zoom

// 4. geoFire ref
let geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("restaurant_locations")
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef)

// 6. use GeoFire's query(with: region) and this is the radius I want to run the geoFire query on
regionQuery = geoFire.query(with: region)

// 7. observe.keyEntered at that region query
queryHandle = regionQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: {.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in ...

// 8.
regionQuery?.observeReady {
    // do something when the observer from step 7 is finished
}
```